# Get Application Installed Date With Flutter

Tags: flutter

Is there's a way to find out the "Date when an application was installed" on Android & iOS with Flutter

Comment: You want the date of when your app was installed or when any app on that phone was installed?

Comment: I don't know, but you may want to run the feature idea past someone and make sure it accomplishes what you want. Besides informational value for curious people, there is nothing you could do with that information. I can install, delete and reinstall an app as many times as I want and for any reason I want. If the Date is "a minute ago", that doesn't mean I am new, I could have had it for ten years, just reinstalled it a minute ago.

Comment: @SiddharthAgrawal the date of my app

Comment: The store should be able to return the license acquired date, this is the date when the user first installed the app. Dev can use this to implement timed trial version, honeymoon period and the like. Is it possible to get this from the google and apple stores?

Answer (score 2):

use this plugin :

https://pub.dev/packages/device_apps

in `Application` class `installTimeMillis` is Installed date of app

```dart
List<Application> apps = await DeviceApps.getInstalledApplications();

apps.forEach((app) {
  DateTime installDate = 
    DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(
      app.installTimeMillis
    );
  print(installDate);
});
```

Comment: This works only in android, What about iOS?

Answer (score 1):

There is this package which works on Android and iOS: [app_install_date](https://pub.dev/packages/app_install_date)

> On Android it is using the PackageManager to get install date from the
> package info
>
> On iOS and MacOS platforms it is using application document
> directory's creation date. This method is also used in native
> development

Here is an example on how to use it:

```
DateTime installDate;
// Platform messages may fail, so we use a try/catch 
try {
    installDate = await AppInstallDate().installDate;
} catch (e) {
    //handle error here
}
```

More info [here](https://pub.dev/packages/app_install_date)